# Unity3d GetPixels не изменяет текстуру

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется следующая ситуация: в Unity  - у меня есть некий материал содержащий некую текстуру.
Стоит следующая задача: при скролинге мышью по игровому объекту с данным материалом - рисовать линии на объекте - т.е как в Paint - но в realTime и по любому объекту на сцене.
Для этого я добавил к объекту скрипт содержащий метод Draw:

public void Draw()

```
{

    Vector2 MouseVector = new Vector2(OnMouseUp(),OnMouseDown());
   Vector2 ImageVector = new Vector2( MainSHDtexture.width,MainSHDtexture.height);
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageVector.magnitude; i++)
    {
        if (MouseVector.x<=ImageVector.x && MouseVector.y <= ImageVector.x) 
        {
            int K = System.Convert.ToInt32(MouseVector.y);
            int L = System.Convert.ToInt32(MouseVector.x);
            for (K++; i < ImageVector.x; i++)
            {
                for (L++; i < ImageVector.y; i++)
                {

                    Texture2D tx = (Texture2D)MainSHDtexture;
                    tx.SetPixel(K , L , Color.white);
                    tx.Apply();
                    MainSHDtexture = tx;
                }

            }

        }
        else if (MouseVector.y >= ImageVector.x ) 
        {
            int K = System.Convert.ToInt32(MouseVector.y);
            for (K++; i < ImageVector.y; i++)
            {
                Texture2D tx = (Texture2D)MainSHDtexture;
                tx.SetPixel(K , System.Convert.ToInt32( ImageVector.x), Color.white);
                tx.Apply();
                MainSHDtexture = tx;

            }
        }

        else if (MouseVector.x <= ImageVector.y)
        {
            int K = System.Convert.ToInt32(MouseVector.x);
            for (K++; i < ImageVector.y; i++)
            {
                Texture2D tx = (Texture2D)MainSHDtexture;
                tx.SetPixel(K , System.Convert.ToInt32(ImageVector.y) , Color.white);
                tx.Apply();
                MainSHDtexture = tx;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Идею скрипта в следующем чем-то похожа на IntervalTree -  пусть передвижения мыши можно задать как вектор - где его начало это нажатие кнопки, а его конец - соответственно- случай когда мы отпускаем кнопку мыши.

Соответственно в `OnMouseUp() и OnMouseDown()` - я возвращая координаты мыши X и Y

Точно так же в виде вектора можно задать и текстуру - начиная от ширины - заканчивая высотой - получится один отрезок суммарной длины.

Т.е сама задача сводится заменить пиксели из вектора ImageVector на все пиксели длины MouseVector. Я предпологая, что эт вектора не пересекаются, а параллельны, причем MouseVector - лежит "выше" ImageVector  - и проекция MouseVector -это то самое количество пикселей необходимое для замены.

Далее я рассматриваю три случая - полной проекции MouseVector  в ImageVector  , проекции только головы MouseVector  в начало ImageVector   и проекции хвоста MouseVector   в  ImageVector  .

Также хочу отметить что `K++` - сделано от безвыходности  - т.к разрешены только операции инкремента, дикремента и создания нового объекта.

Студиия и Unity ошибок не выдает, но скрипт не выполняет поставленной задачи - т.е не сетит нужные пиксели текстуры в нужный цвет.

Также смотрел под Debug с помощью точек-останова - скрипт при выполнении заходит во второй блок if (тот который else if).

Запись/чтение в свойствах текстуры  - при импорте  -разрешил.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Проверьте что у вас ссылочка на текстуру в скрипте соответствует ссылке которая используется при отрисовке в сцене. Возможно у вас копия материала создается, и поэтому ваши изменения не заметны извне, что они делаются в объекте который мы не видим. Поставьте на паузу в момент исполнения и зайдите в текстуру  материала с которым работаете, посмотрите фиксируются ли в ней изменения.

Answer (score 2):

После того, как вы применяете `SetPixel` или `SetPixels` к текстуре, вы обязательно должны вызывать метод [Texture2D.Apply()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html), для того, чтобы записать ваши изменения в текстуру. Если не вызывать этот метод, то вы не увидите никаких изменений.

Также, хочу заметить, что применение `SetPixel` или `SetPixels` к тексутрам, будет работать только для текстур без сжатия. То есть к примеру для сжатия PVRTC(iOS нативное сжатие) данные методы работать не будут и вы получите ошибку в консоли.

Comment: спасибо за ответ - я применил Apply как Вы и советовали, но результат это не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение - вот где была проблема:

```
Vector2 MouseVector = new Vector2(OnMouseUp(),OnMouseDown());
```

они не сработают вместе